# How to Create our own Custom Component in MudBlazor

Tags: checkbox, components, href, custom-component, mudblazor

My Own Custom component with MudNavLink and MudCheckBox but it didn't show in Implemented Razor Page output. I didn't know issue i was using own component for first time.

**CustomLinkWithCheckbox.razor**

```
    <div style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
    <MudNavLink Href="@Href" Class="@Class" Icon="@Icon">
        @LinkText
         <div class="checkbox-link">
            <MudCheckBox @bind-Checked="IsChecked" />
        </div>
    </MudNavLink>
    </div>

    @code {
    [Parameter] public string Href { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string LinkText { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string Text { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string Class { get; set; }
    
    [Parameter] public string Icon { get; set; }
}
```

**ImplementedPage.razor**

```
<CustomLinkWithCheckbox Href="/dashboard" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Dashboard" LinkText="My Dashboard" @bind-IsChecked="@isdashboardChecked" />
@code {
 private bool isdashboardChecked { get; set; }
}
```

**I was trying to create MudNavLink and MudCheckBox are two components as one(own custom Component)**

```
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center custom-nav-link">
    <MudNavLink Href="/dashboard" IconColor="Color.Secondary" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Dashboard">My Dashboard </MudNavLink>
    <MudCheckBox @bind-Checked="@isdashboardChecked" class="mud-checkbox" Color="Color.Primary" CheckedIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Star" UncheckedIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.StarOutline" Size="Size.Small"></MudCheckBox>
    </div>
```

that is  my own custom component

```
    <div style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
    <MudNavLink Href="@Href" Class="@Class" Icon="@Icon">@LinkText
         <div class="checkbox-link">
           <MudCheckBox @bind-Checked="IsChecked" />
        </div>
    </MudNavLink>
    </div>
```

But i didn't reflect in my Implemented Razor page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just that. You don't need anything else. But in your case the custom component has an error and is therefore not being rendered.

Instead of

`<CustomLinkWithCheckbox ... @bind-IsChecked="@isdashboardChecked" />`

you should use

`<CustomLinkWithCheckbox ... @IsChecked="@isdashboardChecked" />`

Check out this [Snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wkcouFEdouuMvkRj)

With `@bind-Value` you are creating an EventCallback `ValueChanged`.
For more info: [ASP.NET Core Blazor data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0)